# Linux Kernel: Hot and Cold page in linux kernel

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

Can somebody explain exact difference between Hot and Cold pages in linux page-allocation process? use [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/14768/)

And, In any way is it related to `page_order`?

```
void __free_pages(struct page *page, unsigned int order)
{
    if (put_page_testzero(page)) {
        if (order == 0)
            free_hot_cold_page(page, false);
        else
            __free_pages_ok(page, order);
    }
}
```

Comment: [hot and cold pages in linux page-allocation process](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hot%20and%20cold%20pages%20in%20linux%20page-allocation%20process)

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/14768/